# Overlapping oval borders CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a football-looking container for my site, with 3 different colors. I am doing this by having containers within containers, but the borders are stacking on top of each other in the bottom right of the containers. How do I make it so it is all properly centered?

[image]

I tried messing with position tags and that did not seem to work.

```css
body {
  background: #0a1629;
}

.logo {
  height: 35vw;
  max-height: 270px;
  width: 65vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1vw solid #c73804;
}

.middle-ring {
  height: 35.5vw;
  max-height: 274px;
  width: 65.5vw;
  max-width: 504px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1vw solid #ffffff;
}

.outer-ring {
  height: 36vw;
  max-height: 278px;
  width: 66vw;
  max-width: 508px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1vw solid #c73804;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-ring">
  <div class="middle-ring">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit your question and add code here, don't upload pictures

Comment: How did you calculate your `height`, `max-height`, `width`, and `max-width` values? Is it possible to include an image of how you intend it to look?

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of your innermost ring, but then allow the outer rings to size themselves based on their contents, by styling them with `display: inline-block`. Each ring will then wrap snugly around the previous one.

[image: rings around logo in correct arrangement]

```css
body {
  margin: 3vw;
  background: #0a1629;
}

.red-ring, .white-ring {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.white-ring {
  border: 1vw solid #ffffff;
}

.red-ring {
  border: 1vw solid #e64100;
}

.logo {
  height: 35vw;
  width: 65vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-ring">
  <div class="white-ring">
    <div class="logo red-ring">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Chicago_Bears_logo.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```